# tkinter window freezes after some time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter. I was experimenting with this, but while the Tkinter starts just fine, it some times freezes after a while for no reason. Actually, the weird thing that happens, is that while the Tkinter windows do not update the information anymore, the counter keeps printing ON MY WINDOWS DESKTOP LEFT TOP SIDE! (just the black bg box with the white font that shows the counter number) and eventually finds number 777 and ends. But long freezes in between, even without any printing (not on my Windows desktop either)

[this is the normal tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2owwm.png)
[this is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ8dC.png)
all good here

[crazy Windows display here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVj9Y.png)

The simple program here is generating random ints from 1 - 10000 and should 1) if 777 is found it should print the counter and exit  2) if any number between 1-100 is found, it should print the number and counter.

I am trying to learn how to print new content in the same line, and if something happens print more info on another line, while the first (or more) keep updating.

I'm not sure if I exit the program the right way or how exactly I should be using/calling the Tkinter function to update the info on the screen.

Any help or tips most appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

tk=Tk()
i = 0
counter = 0

tk.title("Testing...")
tk.geometry('300x200')

canvas_width = 200
canvas_height = 100
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg='white')
canvas.pack(expand=YES)

def screen(Found):
    #canvas.create_text(20, 20, text="Counter:" + str(counter), font="Times 20 italic")
    widget = Label(canvas, text="Counter:" + str(counter), fg='white', bg='black')
    widget.grid(column=0, row=0)
    if Found:
        widget = Label(canvas, text="Number " + str(i) +" was found at counter:" + str(counter), fg='white', bg='black')
        widget.grid(column=0, row=1)

found = False

loop = True
while loop:
    counter += 1
    i = random.randint(1, 10000)

    if i in range(1, 100):
        print("Found i = ", i, " in counter:", counter)
        Found = True
    else:
        Found = False

    if i == 777:
        loop = False
        print("JUST FOUND 777")
        print("Counter:", counter)

    screen(Found)
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()

# tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's impossible for us to diagnose your problem without it.

Comment: Hi Bryan and thank you. I added 2 screenshots when the program is running if they help. The problem is that after a while, the Tkinter shows nothing and is like frozen, even its window shows "not responding". But, after a while, it might continue or print on the top left side of my desktop. The sure thing is, that it stops refreshing and displaying the counter or anything else that updates.

Comment: just managed to get the 'crazy' screenshot

Comment: The "crazy display" is what appeared in the command prompt terminal window because of the `print("Counter:", counter)` call you have in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of design, it is usually a better approach to rely on the tkinter mainloop to drive the application. `root.after` is a great substitute to a while loop. Labels do not need to be recreated; they can use special variables that update the displayed values themselves, and their properties can be reconfigured. Calling `update`, and `update_idletasks` is hardly ever needed.

The following is maybe a better approach where one single label is updated from a loop powered by the tkinter mainloop:
(it shows you *"how to keep displaying new stuff, without such label issues"*)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def screen(found, v, c):
    if found:
        label.configure(bg='red', fg='blue')
        print('found')
    else:
        label.configure(bg='black', fg='white')
    update_lbl_txt(v, c)

def update_lbl_txt(v=0, c=0):
    txt = f'Number at {v} was found at counter {c}'
    lbl_txt.set(txt)

def found_target(t):
    return t in range(1, 100) or t == 777

def loop(c=0):
    v = random.randint(1, 10000)
    screen(found_target(v), v, c)
    root.after(100, loop, c+1)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Testing...")
root.geometry('300x200')

lbl_txt = tk.StringVar(root)
update_lbl_txt()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=lbl_txt, fg='white', bg='black')
label.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

loop()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: WOW Redblochon. This is a great piece of code. Run it, works smoothly. 

Question 1:What if I want to do some more work inside the loop, instead of just counting up a number? Say, I work some math, get the result and if it matches what I'm looking for, then display that instead of just the word 'found' and flash the windows (nice touch there)?

Comment: Question 2: How does the root.after(100... affect the performance of loop()? This is important to me especially if the work inside it will need all the 'juice' from the CPU it can get.

Question 3: Would it be possible that any time the 'found' (and color flash) occurs, I can get the 'found' word (or my result) printed on the same tkinter window (maybe 1-2 lines under it, or with scrolling each new line, or... another tkinter window?

Again, great code. I honestly appreciate your time and your solution. Thank you.

Comment: ...also, how do I exit the program normally, if I decide to do so? For example, if I add a key-pressed check? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you can do all that; I encourage you to try, you will learn something doing so, and to please ask a new question if you are having difficulties.

Comment: I will try my best and report back here. What about Question 2? Is the 100 ms ok to use for running a 'hungry' loop of calculations? Is this only related to how this loop def reacts? It's not clear to me how this delay affects the rest of the work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it seems to freeze it at least partly because you have an infinite loop that you never, ever break out of. Most of the time `i` will not be in the range of 1 to 100, nor will it be 777, but your loop will keep on running and never update the screen.

You're also creating hundreds or thousands of label widgets every second, stacked on top of one another. You will run into performance issues rather quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Bryan, I know about the loop. It is not infinite, as the reason it looks for 777 out of 10000 is just to keep it going for a while generating counters to use for displaying updated info in Tkinter.


As for the thousands of labels, this is where I don't know much, can you please help in telling me how to keep displaying new stuff, without such label issues?